# Get size of email attachment

Tags: email, attachment, heap

I'm hitting the heap size limit when converting attachments to base64. I've already put it in a future and running at 3xheap. What I want to do is get the size of the attachment prior to conversion and deal with it another way, but for some reason I can't seem to find any way to get the size of it? I've searched and can't seem to find an answer to this issue... surely I'm not the lucky one!

The full picture is I get inbound emails with attachments, I do some processing around the contents and then I need to send an email out to people. So I have access to both the inbound and outbound emails, I just can't find a way to get the size of anything in bytes. I'd be happy with the total email size including attachments, or just individual attachment sizes. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure how you are processing, but querying bodylength field of an attachment would return the size of the file in bytes.

Comment: I don't believe that works for attachments for emails (Messaging.InboundEmail & Messaging.SingleEmailMessage). This isn't an Attachment to an Object.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right. EmailMessage object is a parent of the Attachment. ParentId field of an attachment references to the EmailMessage.

Comment: Sure. Give a shot and post updates.

Comment: @Seesh -- `EmailMessage` sObject applies only to `Email2Case` and not the Apex Inbound Email Service

Comment: see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_binary.htm#apex_classes_email_inbound_binary (binary attachments) and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_text.htm#apex_classes_inbound_text (text attachments). The `body` property can be used to get size

Comment: oops. sturev - sorry for misguiding you. crop1645 - Thanks for striking the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
        Integer emailSize = email.plainTextBody.length();
        // check attachments
        if(email.binaryAttachments != null) {
            for(Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment file : email.binaryAttachments) {
                emailSize = emailSize + file.body.size();
            }
        }
        if(email.textAttachments != null) {
            for(Messaging.InboundEmail.TextAttachment file : email.textAttachments) {
                emailSize = emailSize + file.body.length();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) `BodyLength` attribute gives you Attachment `Size of the file (in bytes).`.

> Update

For `Messaging.InboundEmail` you can get all Attachments with  `email.binaryAttachments` convert them to `Attachment` and get the size.

```
if (email.binaryAttachments != null && email.binaryAttachments.size() > 0) {
    for (integer i = 0; i < email.binaryAttachments.size(); i++) {
        Attachment a = new Attachment(ParentId = <Parent Id>,
        Name = email.binaryAttachments[i].filename,
        Body = email.binaryAttachments[i].body);
        System.debug(a.BodyLength);
    }
}
```

http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/retrieving-email-attachments-and-associating-them-with-records
http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/06/what-are-email-services-in-salesforce.html

Comment: I don't believe that works for attachments for emails (Messaging.InboundEmail & Messaging.SingleEmailMessage). This isn't an Attachment to an Object.

Comment: @sturev Please check my updated answer, hope this helps.

Comment: n.b. no need to convert to Attachment, use `body` property (type=Blob) and then Blob method `size()`